# Is a compression function call the same as invoking the hash function itself?

Tags: hash, blake2, compression-function

In [BLAKE2X paper](https://www.blake2.net/blake2x.pdf) it is said:

> BLAKE2X adds a constant overhead of $\lceil\ell/64\rceil$ (resp. $\lceil\ell/32\rceil$ compression function calls compared to the underlying 64-bit (resp. 32-bit) BLAKE2 hash. For example, to compute a 1056-bit (132-byte) hash as required in Ed521 signatures, BLAKE2X adds† $\lceil132/64\rceil=3$ extra compression function calls compared to BLAKE2b. Note that $\operatorname{B2}(i,j,H_0)$ calls can be computed in arbitrary order, and in parallel.

Is a compression function call the same as a invoking of the hash function itself?

In BLAKE2X there is also this notation:
$$\operatorname{B2}(0,64,H_0)\mathbin\|\operatorname{B2}(1,64,H_0)\mathbin\|\ldots\mathbin\|\operatorname{B2}(\lfloor\ell/64\rfloor,\ell\bmod64,H_0)$$

Are these concatenated values successive calls to the hash function itself?

This question can sound obvious, but I am not a very good English reader and I am little confused about timing when generating a 1GiB stream with BLAKE2X using a 64-byte seed compared to using a 40KiB one:

```
$ time dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=64 2>/dev/null | /usr/local/bin/b2sum -X 8589934592 > /dev/null 

real    0m7.058s
user    0m6.273s
sys 0m0.785s

$ time dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=1073741824 2>/dev/null | /usr/local/bin/b2sum -X 8589934592 > /dev/null

real    0m9.295s
user    0m7.669s
sys 0m2.018s
```

/\ Too much fast and good for me. Maybe the seed is stored in L1/L2 cache (that should have a [speed of 1TiB/s](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/memory-performance-in-a-nutshell.html))

---

† with an obvious fix from the original $\lceil132/3\rceil=3$

Comment: I see $\operatorname{B2}$ defined on the last third of [page 2](https://www.blake2.net/blake2x.pdf#page=2).

Comment: @fgrieu "Create the hash function instance B2 from the BLAKE2 instance used..." I was a little confused about what would be a compression function call, if it's the same of invoking the hash function.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are. Specifically as pointed out by @fgrieu,

> $B2(i, j, X)$ denotes the hash of $X$ using $i$ as node offset and $j$ as digest length.

And as stated in the paper, the calls need not be successive, they can be computed in any order, or in parallel. Furthermore, each invocation of $B2(i,j,X)$ makes Blake2 call its' round function only once, therefore these calls are *light* compared to the usual scenario for typical hash function invocations where the compression function is called many times.

Comment: Addition: and each invocation of $\operatorname{B2}(i, j, X)$ makes Blake2 call it's round function a single time.

Comment: Now I know why the timing are the near same for short or long inputs, BLAKE2X condensates entropy from the source into a key and hash this key using different node offsets, I thought it was reading directly the input, that's why I didn't understand. I'm curious to know the extracted key size: https://github.com/BLAKE2/BLAKE2/blob/54f4faa4c16ea34bcd59d16e8da46a64b259fc07/ref/blake2xb-ref.c -- I tried to take a look in BLAKE2X reference implementation but I don't know how to read C.